# How to point to const int 2d array?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, constants

Let's assume that my class has two const int 2-dimensional arrays. I also have a method, that gets bool variable from a user and basing on its value it chooses one of the matrixes to use it in further calculations. How can I refer to one of this matrixes ? For example, if user provides 'true' method will operate on matrix_1, and if user provides 'false' method will operate on matrix_2. Here is the example code:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        const int matrix_1[2][2] = { {1,1} ,{2,2} };
        const int matrix_2[3][3] = { {1,2,3} ,{3,4,5}, {6,7,8} };
        Foo() {}
        void method(bool select) {
            //pointer variable pt
            if (select == true) {
                //pt points to matrix_1
            }
            else {
                //pt points to matrix_2
            }
            //some calculations 
        }

};
```

Comment: Write a matrix class and then have and array/vector of matrices in your class.  Then you can use an index to which matrix you want to use.

Comment: Pointers to 2D arrays are hard to do without doing something technically illegal. They aren't `T*` and they aren't `T**` In this case they're `int * [2]` and `int * [3]` and those aren't the same type. Yuck yuck yuck. Take the above advice and use a wrapper class.

Comment: Agreed. C++ doesn't really like to mix in C-like pointers. Using a vector of vectors is probably better. You're mixing arrays of different sizes, which will make your pointer arithmetic hard as well. If you really want to do this, a void** would work, and then you also need to carry around the matrix size information separately.